# Can I insert break point into source perl program?

Tags: perl, debugging

I want the perl program launch debugger when some condition hit. Some other language has debug() statement supported by library, is there any similar statement in perl?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried adding the -d switch to the shebang line at the top of your script? Something like

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -d
use strict;
use warnings;
$|=1;$\="\n";

print "Test";
```

It really depends exactly how it gets launched, but at least in simple cases this should start the debugger.

Edit:
You can then set a breakpoint on a specific line with a certain condition using

```
> b [line] [condition]
```

and hit

```
> c
```

to continue with running the script - the debugger will stop at the specified line when the condition is met

Comment: That is great. Is there similar syntax on windows?

Comment: I believe perl will respect the switches even if the actual perl executable launching is not the one listed in the shebang - ie, even if the above script is started as, say,    C:\Perl\bin\perl.exe script.pl, it should still start the debugger

Answer (score 36):

If I understand you correctly, you need to use a specific debugger variable in your code - `$DB::single`. Setting this to a true value in your code will cause the debugger to stop on that line.

```
$x = 1234;
$DB::single = 1;
enter_problematic_sub_now();
```

Your code will then stop at the line with $DB::single set to 1.

Of course, if you can't actually ensure that your code is running in the debugger then you have another problem entirely. You *will* need to run your code via `perl -d` as well.

Comment: Do you mean if my program doesn't run in debugger, I can't use $DB::single as expected?

Comment: @Thompson: Yes, that's right. If you want a Perl program to be debugged, you must run it under a debugger. To the best of my knowledge, this kind of thing holds true for most sorts of source-based real-time debugging in other languages — postmortems of coredumps notwithstanding.

Comment: @tchrist I'm not sure how it works internally in Python, but I can do `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` anywhere in the code to break at that point and enter the debugger. I don't have to run the script with any special debug modifiers.

Answer (score 2):

Well, there is something which will enable you to do something like breakpoints, but the functionality is wider: [Perl Debugger](http://p3rl.org/debug).

Comment: Can this work when I can't change the launch method (the command line to perl executable)?

Comment: the launch method is essential, you cannot use the debugger without option -d

Answer (score 2):

> Essentially the `-d` switch allows you to communicate with the perl executable, and allows the perl executable to communicate with you.

[More](http://p3rl.org/debtut)

Comment: My piece of perl code is part of large system, and i can't control how it is launched. It seems i can only revise to source file to do so.

Comment: @Thomson Tan: In that case, logging would work better. Take a look at [Log::Log4perl](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Log::Log4perl).